# Is it possible to return the primitive values of instances of String & Number?

Tags: javascript

It seems instances of `String` & `Number` have a hidden property called `[[PrimitiveValue]]` that contains a primitive value associated with the instance.

Is it possible to convert instances of `String` & instances of `Number` into string and number primitives - or at least return the primitive value associated with these instances?

Comment: Do you mean [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)?

Comment: @tadman That works, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is accessible via [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) if you need to probe to the underlying primitive value of a wrapper object.